# Set new column values in pandas DataFrame1 where DF2 column values match DF1 index

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'd like to set a new column in a pandas dataframe with values calculated using a groupby on dataframe2.

DF1:

```
     col1    col2
id    
 1    'a'
 2    'b'
 3    'c'
```

DF2:

```
          id    col2
 index    
     1     1      11
     1     1      22
     1     1      12
     1     1      45
     3     3      83
     3     3      11
     3     3      35
     3     3      54
```

I want to group DF2 by 'id', and then apply a function on 'col2' to put the result into the corresponding index in DF1. If there is no group for that particular index, then I want to fill with NaN...

```
ret_val = DF2.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: my_func(x['col_2']))

     col1    col2
id    
 1    'a'    ret_val
 2    'b'    NaN
 3    'c'    ret_val
```

... I can't quite figure out how to achieve this though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the function on col2 of df2 first then use `pd.concat` droping the `col2` in df since it is empty.

```
x = df2.groupby('id')['col2'].apply(sum) # instead of sum use your own function
ndf = pd.concat([df.drop('col2',1),x],1)
```

```
   col1   col2
id            
1   'a'   90.0
2   'b'    NaN
3   'c'  183.0
```

Straight and simple suggested by @Zero

```
df1['col2'] = df2.groupby('id')['col2'].apply(sum)
```

Comment: Actually, `df1['col2'] = df2.groupby('id')['col2'].apply(sum)` would just do?

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` on `df1.index` series.

```
In [5327]: df1['col2'] = df1.index.to_series().map(df2.groupby('id')
                                                      .apply(lambda x: my_func(x['col2'])))

In [5328]: df1
Out[5328]:
   col1   col2
id
1     a  360.0
2     b    NaN
3     c  536.0
```

Details

```
In [5322]: def my_func(x):
      ...:     return x.sum()
      ...:

In [5323]: df2.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: my_func(x['col2']))
Out[5323]:
id
1    360.0
3    536.0
dtype: float64

In [5324]: df1.index.to_series().map(df2.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: my_func(x['col2'])))
Out[5324]:
id
1    360.0
2      NaN
3    536.0
Name: id, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

you can replace `sum` with `.apply(lambda x : your_func(x))`

```
df1.col2=df.set_index('id').groupby(level='id').sum()
df1
Out[975]: 
   col1   col2
id            
1   'a'   90.0
2   'b'    NaN
3   'c'  183.0
```

Comment: `df1.col2=df.groupby('id').sum()` should do?

Comment: @Zero yeah , You got it , Over thinking ...LOL

Comment: Even did I think too much. TBH @Zero also thought too much haha